# Expressing a time in natural language, rounded to five-minute intervals

Tags: python, date, format

I want to write a time formatter, `time_format(hours, minutes)`, that takes a time of day, expressed in hours and minutes, rounds it to the nearest 5 minutes, and expresses it in English words.

I need to write a method that formats input such as

```
"9,1"
```

Into "nine o'clock"

```
time_format(9, 1) returns "nine o'clock"
time_format(9, 5) returns "five after nine"
time_format(9, 13) returns "quarter after nine"
time_format(9, 9) returns "ten after nine"
time_format(9, 20) returns "twenty after nine"
time_format(9, 24) returns "twenty five after nine"
time_format(9, 30) returns "half past nine"
time_format(9, 36) returns "twenty five to ten"
time_format(9, 38) returns "twenty to ten"
time_format(9, 45) returns "quarter to ten"
time_format(9, 50) returns "ten to ten"
time_format(9, 56) returns "five to ten"
time_format(12, 00) returns "noon"
time_format(15, 20) returns "twenty after three"
time_format(23, 45) returns "a quarter to midnight"
```

Any idea how I can do this? I've been looking at the date object but it hasn't given me a way to supply a number like 20 and get the literal text for it.

Comment: What have you tried? You have to post a specific question for us to answer. To just do all your work for you would be immoral, and would stunt your growth. I'd be happy to help if you show a little more work. I have a few ideas, actually!

Comment: The requirements are pretty vague. If you can provide a precise specification for the output, that would help us answer, and would also guide you to think through the problem. (By the way, is this homework? It really looks like homework.)

Comment: Date objects won't help. I'd actually recommend completely ignoring the standard library for this problem.

Comment: I agree, don't use anything, actually, besides if, elif, and print really, and you can do it. I just finished my prototype. This is a neat question.

Comment: So far, I thought about just doing it the dirty way - a dictionary with the numbers. That worked for 1-24, but I realized I can't do it for all the time. It won't let me post my dictionary code.

Comment: options =  { 1 : hours = "one",
                2 : hours = "two,
                3 : hours = "three,
                4 : hours = "four,
                5 : hours = "five,
                6 : hours = "six,
                7 : hours = "seven,
                8 : hours = "eight,
   }

Comment: Write a super-fancy time formatter, time_format(h,m), that takes a time of day, expressed in hours and minutes, rounds it to the nearest 5 minutes, and expresses it as a string. is the question, and yes this is homework. I just have no idea what to do for this one.

Comment: Does the question actually say anything about using words like "five", "midnight", or "quarter"? If it does, a lot of the code is just going to be a dict or two mapping numbers to names. I don't see a better way.

Comment: You posted work! Ok, answer incoming!

Comment: Is it possible you can give me a hint instead of posting code?

Comment: @user2417731: well, your tasks seem to be: (a) round to the nearest five minutes; and (b) turn that into a string. These are very distinct questions. Which part are you needing help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, now, you asked for an idea, so this is my nudge in the right direction. I think you're spot on using dictionaries. But what's more important for how you structure your output, the first number or the second?

The second!

But a dictionary won't work for the second case, you need if elif chains. Here is two snippets of the code I used to tackle the second value. Should be easy enough from there, I hope!

```
def time_eval_thingy ( a, b ):
b = int( b ) # probably not needed, just to be sure
if b < 5:
  outputstring = "SPECIAL"
elif b < 10:
  outputstring = "5 after "

...
elif b < 50
  outputstring = "Quarter until "
  a += 1 # a is the hour, and increasing it here will make the hour appear higher in the dictionary call that occurs after the time when we decide the signifcance of b
```

I should add that later I check is output is "SPECIAL" and if it is, I add "O'clock" to the end for a values that are not 12 or 00 (which convert the whole string to noon or midnight)

Comment: I don't get the " rounds it to the nearest 5 minutes, and expresses it as a string.". How is 9 ten after nine? Is it because closest 5 to 9 is 5+5=10? Also I'm wondering how the time chain works. I'm use to just saying 5:10. Not 10 after 5. So do I keep continuing until I reach full 50 minutes? I.e 10 after 5, 15 after 5, 20 after 5 .... 50 after 5? Thanks!

Comment: I think you got the comparisons backward. Also, it's not using the right rounding cutoffs.

Comment: I typed my comparissons backwards, and I used my own rounding cutoffs. This was my own code I wrote, and I was showing it to you as an idea. Your question asks for an idea, no? Do your own rounding and use this as a template. Or do it your own way, I don't mind! This is just the idea I had, and the method I used.

Comment: @user2417731 if you notice, on my last example, I incriment a (which is your hour) when I use the "until" types. The increase on a will reflect when you search a dictionary.

Comment: I think you got the guy who asked for a clarification of the question (not code) and teh guy who picked on your code confused. I'm not the guy who picked on your code. I was just hoping you understood the question better than I did.

Comment: Yeah, no, I got confused, didnt realize who was who, sorry! If `b < 5` I am going to say "9 o clock" or "noon" or whatever. if `b < 10` I'll just say b is basically 5 and say "5 after" and so on until `b = 30` at which time I will say "half past 9", and then at `b < 45` I switch it up and if a = 9, I'll say "Quarter until 10" which I do by increasing a by one and just saying  "Quarter until" later in my code I look at `a` value and use it to call a dictionary by saying `output += time_dict[a]`

Comment: @user2417731 Does that make sense? I'm not great at explanations all the time.

Comment: Yeah it is a bit. Is there a site that explains these "quarter" after "half after" etc, stuff for time?

Comment: @user2417731 Uh... "quarter" means 15 and "half" means 30 and that's about it for time, I think. Quarter is actually `1/4` and `1/4` of an hour is 15 minutes.